# Nopcommerce - want to check if admin is login or not in front end

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am using `Nopcommerce` and I want to check if admin is login or not in front end.

I have created one `button` and by default it will be disabled.

If admin login in front end then only that `button` will be enabled, so can any one help me how can I check if admin is login or not.

Thanks

Comment: This is already done by NopCommerce in the template provided.  If you are logged in an Admin link appears at the top of every page.  You need to look how this works.

Answer (score 1):

```
@using Nop.Core.Infrastructure;
@using Nop.Core;
@using Nop.Core.Domain.Customers;


@{
    var _workContext = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWorkContext>();
    var isUserAdmin = _workContext.CurrentCustomer.IsAdmin();
}

@if(isUserAdmin)
{
//your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get it working, so I am posting solution here if any one needed.

@inject IWorkContext workContext

```
@if (workContext.CurrentCustomer.IsAdmin())
{
 //Here write code 
}
```